# No matching version found for commander@2.18.1. in Angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, angular6, npm-install

I cloned project from git and try to enter **npm install**. So it is telling like

[image]

Why im getting this and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such version 2.18.1 for commander. Check this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander?activeTab=versions

Try changing to latest version 8.1.0 in package.json file and try npm install again.

Comment: Assuming that the project maintainers for `commander` follow SemVer rules then try changing it to version `2.20.3`. It's likely to be more compatible than `8.1.0` because there's no change to the _MAJOR_ version. i.e. version `2.20.3` should have no incompatible API changes, unlike `8.1.0`.